# Bootstrap collapse not working properly when partial view loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap collapse is working properly but when the partial view loads on the same view, that's where the issue starts.

if i click the button to collapse the div it just blinks but don't collapse.

Here's the view :

```
 <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>Dashboard</h1><small><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible">Toggle</button></small>
        </section>
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="collapse" id="collapsible">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>150</h3>
                                <p>New Orders</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- ./col -->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-green">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>53<sup style="font-size: 20px">%</sup></h3>
                                <p>Bounce Rate</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- ./col -->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>44</h3>
                                <p>User Registrations</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- ./col -->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-red">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>65</h3>
                                <p>Unique Visitors</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info **strong text**<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- ./col -->
                </div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->
            <!-- Main row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Left col -->
                <section id="Results" class="col-lg-12">*This is where the partial view loads.</section>
            </div>
        </section><!-- /.content -->
    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Then this is the javascript to load the partial view on a button click:

```
   <script>
    document.getElementById("showresults").onclick = function () { ViewResults() };
    function ViewResults() {
        $("#Results").load("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Results","Dashboard"))");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Is this a live webpage? Can you provide a link to the page with the problem?

Comment: Sorry but it's not a live webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is executed in client-side and I believe it does not translate `@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Results","Dashboard"))` into HTML. It is your ASP.NET that must translate it into HTML. It outputs string `@Html.Raw()` as it is. Try to inspect DOM element at run-time using browser tool.

Make sure you escape double quote (") character for example `@Html.Raw(Url.Action(\"Results\",\"Dashboard\"))` otherwise your javascript will not work.

Try to something like this

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("showresults").onclick = function () { ViewResults() };
   function ViewResults() {
       $("#Results").load("<div>This is just test</div>");
}
```

and see it it works.

Comment: does this one affects the collapse ?

Comment: What can I use besides Html.Raw() ?

Comment: If javascript contains syntax error, then collapse will not work.

Comment: What can I use then besides Html.Raw() ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
$("#Results").load("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Results","Dashboard"))");

try this

$("#Results").load('Url.Action("Results","Dashboard")');

Comment: Tried this already but bootstrap collapse still isn't working properly :(

Comment: Dont render layout or css on partial view page and try it.